# Reverse the email numbering in mutt

Tags: email, email-client, mutt

How can I reverse the email numbering in mutt? I prefer to have the latest email in the bottom row, which can be achieved by the following settings

```
set sort=threads
set sort_aux=last-date-received     # date of the last message in thread
```

But the numbering is still the latest the largest number. I want to have the smallest number for the latest message. How can I achieve that?